# "True" being printed at the bottom of "Body" node when hovering mouse on element on page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is the page I'm facing issues with: https://twenty3extreme.bluesynergy.me/adventures/scheduled-departures/

Every time I hover on an event in the calendar, the word "true" gets printed at the bottom of the page. I don't understand what's causing it to get printed, and I can't select it in any meaningful way (js, css).

I have tried disabling plugins, disabling my own scripts, monitoring event listeners in Chrome DevTools in the Sources panel, and I've tried looking at events triggered in the Firefox DevTools.

Unfortunately, I don't have code to show, because I can't find the code that's causing the issue.

Ideally I would like to find out what's causing the issue, and fixing it. Alternatively, I could do with a solution that simply hides this text, as it doesn't seem to interrupt the website's functionality at all.

Comment: You'll have to go through all those imported scripts and find out where you're appending to the body. As it stands, it's too needle in the haystack and you'll have to narrow it down and show code

Comment: I feel like you just reiterated what I wrote.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree that this is not an appropriate question, after doing a search on some imported files I'm quite sure that the cause is at wp-content/plugins/eventer/js/eventer_calendar.js, at the eventMouseover handler, line 46: $("body").append(tooltip);

I don't know the purpose to do that, and tooltip variable (initialized in the previous line as calEvent.metas) is not used anymore. Try editing this file to remove this line and check if this fixes your problem.